# Backbone reset event bound to collection not firing when collection is loaded with data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am new to Backbone and started by working through the Todos example.  After that I created a new version of the example, for Contacts rather than Todos, that uses a Ruby on Rails web app and and it's associated REST API rather than localstorage for persistence.  After making the modifications I am able to successfully have the Backbone app update the Rails app but I cannot get the Backbone views to render the data that the Backbone app receives from the Rails REST API.  I have stepped through the code in the debugger and can see that:

1. the events that call the functions to populate the views are being bound to the collection of models
2. when I fetch the model data the collection is getting updated with the data from the server
3. however, the reset event bound to the collection does not fire

Can anybody point me to what might be causing the reset event to not fire?  My code is below:

**Collection**:

```
var ContactsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Contact,
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/contacts.json',
});

var Contacts = new ContactsList;
```

**AppView:**

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: $("#contactapp"),
  events: {
    "keypress #new-contact":  "createOnEnter"
  },

  initialize: function() {

    this.input = this.$("#new-contact");

    Contacts.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
    Contacts.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
    Contacts.bind('all', this.render, this);

    Contacts.fetch();
  },

  addOne: function(contact) {
    var view = new ContactView({model: contact});
    this.$("#contact-list").append(view.render().el);
  },

  addAll: function() {
    Contacts.each(this.addOne);
  },

  createOnEnter: function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    if (!this.input.val()) return;

    Contacts.create({first_name: this.input.val()});
    this.input.val('');
  },

});

var App = new AppView;
```

Comment: so `addAll` is never called when reset occurs?  You've placed a breakpoint there and let it fly?

Comment: Exactly. I've placed break points throughout and can see the events being bound to the collection and the fetch getting the data. From there it just moves on instead of addAll being called. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say, based on your code.  I'd set a breakpoint at lines 746 and 759 of backbone.js, see if the event is triggered and if your functions are bound to the event at that point in time.

Comment: In my backbone.js line 746 is: 'this.iframe.document.open().close();' is this the line you are referring to?

Comment: Try to call `Contacts.reset()` and see if the event is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging I found that the bound `reset` event was not being fired because I was using an old version of backbone.js.  In the version I was using the `refresh` event was being fired not the `reset` event.  Once I upgraded to the newer version of backbone.js the `reset` event fired

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an empty jQuery selector returned by the `el: $("#contactsapp")` configuration in your view.

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/

don't use jQuery selectors as object literal values. with Backbone's view, you can just provide the selector string:

`el: "#contactsapp"`

but this is a bad idea anyways. you should let the view render it's own el, and use other code to populate the "#contactsapp" element with the view:

```
$(function(){
  view = new AppView();
  view.render();
  $("#contacts").html(view.el);
});
```

See the above link for more info.

Comment: I correct this and still have the same issue.  After the Contacts.fetch() the reset event does not fire.